# Forking JVM when using spring-batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, fork

I'm a newbie on Spring-Batch and I want to use it to batch some jobs which use a legacy library. This library has the disadvantages:

- to be not thread-safe
- an instance of some objects in the library cannot handle several jobs in a row (due to enclosed singleton static instances).

Thus, it seems the only solution is to fork the JVM for each job.

My question is: how can i do this using spring-batch ? Most of the solutions in the documentation are thread-oriented.

Comment: how do you run the jobs, with spring batch admin? commandline?

Comment: @MichaelLange I use the Spring Batch API form my main program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"fork the JVM" - how would you do that? Launch a new process altogether? But that won't really  "fork" the JVM - meaning any state information you need to copy to the "child" JVM will have to be done manually.
How about somehow using a different Classloader for each job?

Comment: Yes you're right: i didn't know the JVM was not "libc-like" for forking. Classloader seems a good solution but I'm afraid to face the `PermGenSpace` error, due to multiple static elements not erased by the garbage collector...

Comment: That was something we encountered with Tomcat too during development when we'd redeploy an app many times without restarting the server. Then saw these JVM flags "CMSClassUnloadingEnabled" and "CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled". But by this time one might just think of replacing the legacy library with something else.

Comment: sadly we have to face it: we cannot replace this library at the present time

Comment: @Kartoch, what JRE are you using, "CMSClassUnloadingEnabled" and "CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled" aren't supported?